# React and inline SVG

Tags: reactjs, webpack-2

I tried about 10 svg loaders, react svg inline plugins and such which all failed with Webpack above version 2.

One method does work which is the '-!' prefix before babel-loader

`import Letter from '-!babel-loader!svg-react-loader!./images/letter-m.inline.svg'`

How do can you translate the '-!' prefix to the Webpack config file?

Edit:
Somehow none of the SVG plugins I tested (most of em I found) seem to work. The above example is the only one that worked.

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-samy-svg to easily load SVG files and manipulate them (using proxy elements)

Comment: [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/docs/getting-started/) may be a helpful resource for anyone else stumbling across this question. A tool that converts SVG to React components.